# How to catch exceptions from Action containing anonymous method in c#?

Tags: c#, exception, action, task

Could any one explain, why am I not getting exception from blow code:

```
Action <Exception> myact = ( ) => {       
    throw new Exception( "test" );
  };

  Task myactTask = Task.Factory.StartNew( ( ) => myact);
  try {
    myactTask.Wait( );
    Console.WriteLine( myactTask.Id.ToString( ) );
    Console.WriteLine( myactTask.IsCompleted.ToString( ) );
  }
  catch( AggregateException ex ) {
    throw ex;
  }
```

on the other hand if replace Action "myact" with method "myact()" then I can get exception and it can be handeled with try catch block.

```
public static void myact( ) {
  throw new Exception( "test" );
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the exception in the second case would be caught as the exception handler is only catching `AggregateException` and not the more general `Exception`. Also the call to the anonymous method is **outside** the `try/catch` block. Is this an accurate representation of your code?

Comment: I tried with Exception but it was not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Task myactTask = Task.Factory.StartNew( ( ) => myact);
```

This does not execute your action, it is a function that returns a reference to your Action.

```
Task myactTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(myact);
```

This will execute it and throw/catch the exception.

Comment: Did your code compile to get to this? `Action <Exception> myact = ( ) => {       
    throw new Exception( "test" );
  };` didn't compile for me, I changed it as per my question and calling `() => myact(new Exception("Test")` worked fine so it looks like that does infact execute the action?

Comment: The Action<Exception> needs to be changed to Action to get it to compile, I assume the OP just posted code that was a mix of different attempts. By making your change you start to execute the action which triggers the exception.

Comment: I tried and now things are working and I was missing this piece of information.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you're catching only a `AggregateException` not a `Exception`. Another problem is that you're not really executing your code on `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

Change your code to something like:

```
Action <Exception> myact = ( ) => {       
    throw new Exception("test");
};

Task myactTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(myact);
try {
    myactTask.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine(myactTask.Id.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(myactTask.IsCompleted.ToString());
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    throw ex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I coppied the code and it didn't compile however most of the answers are correct, it is down to what you are trying to catch.

```
//Action<in Exception> : Make the delgate take an exception, then throw it
Action<Exception> myact = (ex => { throw ex; });
//Pass a new Exception with the message test "Test" that will be thrown
Task myactTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => myact(new Exception("Test")));
try
{
  myactTask.Wait();
  Console.WriteLine(myactTask.Id.ToString());
  Console.WriteLine(myactTask.IsCompleted.ToString());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  //Writes out "Test"
  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
  throw ex;
}
```